# npm showing error if though if I edited package.json file

Tags: node.js, npm

sh: 1: to: not found

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.13.0-32-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.12.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! contact@1.0.0 start: `command to run here`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the contact@1.0.0 start script 'command to run here'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the contact package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     command to run here
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs contact
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls contact
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/manukumar/project/Nfriendship/Contact/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: What kind of changes is raising the error? Please add this info to your **question**

Comment: Please update your `package.json` and format your error log.

Comment: you are using npm start, and there is no command specified in package.json corresponding to it. Add the start command.